# Why is my Rails custom error page ignoring a custom layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-error-pages

I have custom dynamic error pages in my Rails 3.2 app.

To ensure that the these error pages don't themselves throw errors, they use a simplified application layout that removes, among other things, dynamic user-account information (ie. like a user avatar in the header) using a simplified layout `application-limited.html.erb`.

```
 # config/application.rb
 config.exceptions_app = self.routes

 # routes.rb
 get '/404', to: 'errors#page_not_found', as: :page_not_found

 # errors_controller.rb
 class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
   def page_not_found
     render status: 404, layout: 'application-limited'
   end
 end
```

When I test by visiting `/404` or `/500` the error page renders correctly with the limited layout. However when I test by visiting a non-existent page `/foobar` I get the correct dynamic 404 error page, but strangely the normal application layout is rendered, rather than the simplified `application-limited` layout.

**What am I missing here?**

*UPDATE:*

Some more experimenting shows that while inheriting `ErrorsController` from `ActionController::Base` as suggested by @BoraMa **does ensure** that when visiting `/404` the default layout is never used, this does not carry over to visting `/foobarxyz` and rendering the custom 404 error page.

There's obviously a reason for this, but I'm yet to work it out!?

Comment: How do you get to the `/404` page during error? Do you have a `rescue_from` in your application controller? Or some special routing? If so, can you show it?

Comment: Thanks BoraMa. I have the standard `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` in my `config/application.rb` to tell Rails my app will handle errors itself in production.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but can you inherit your `ErrorsController` from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ApplicationController`? This way it won't set the default layout and no filters are run which seems a better approach to me anyways.

Comment: Thanks BoraMa, that's a v good suggestion. Strangely the same behaviour persists!? Very weird. I've made sure to turn off any fragment caching too.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I successfully tested your exact scenario, but under rails 4.2 (sorry, it's too difficult to me to test it on Rails 3 right now) and everything seems ok. I also had to set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` in `development.rb` for this to work, but you probably have this too. Couple of ideas: are you absolutely sure this is not cached (is it the same in anon. browser + if you change the 404 page, do you see the changes when you hit a missing page)? Did you perhaps try to update the `/public/404.html` page first, i.e. is it possible that you actually see this page instead?